# C++ Documentation Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

Is there a way to get Visual Studio 2013 to show documentation when I am writing code.  I liked this feature in Netbeans, how it would show me the java docs when I was writing java.  Is there something similar for the STL and windows api?

Comment: @HansPassant I'm not 100% sure, and it may depend on VS version, but I don't think that does anything resembling what OP is asking.

Comment: Maybe the difference is that I checked and verified it works before I posted the comment and you are just guessing that it doesn't work?  Not sure.

Comment: @HansPassanty Well, then you should have written an actual answer, including the version you tested it with... I still doubt it does the same thing, last time I hit F1 in VS it just loaded an MSDN page, but I think I'll have to test myself.

Comment: ...or perhaps chasep255 could clarify the question, if F1 in VS does not do the right thing. Though I think exactly same thing does not exist. Javadoc is quite unique in how ubiquitous it is and how good IDE support it has, helping to keep it up to date.

Comment: Hey I know this was asked a long time ago, but did you manage to find anything regarding your question? I am also facing this issue.

Comment: I don't know what you are talking about exactly, can you please post an image here? But I can give you a suggestion: If that is a so essential feature for you, you can explore the possibility of implementing an Extension. If that extension works also in VS2010, I am also curious to try it.